# How to restrict route params to always only use url-segments?

Tags: asp.net-core

Having a controller method such as:

```
[HttpPost("{name}")]
public Task<IActionResult> HandlePostServiceAction(string name)
```

and then invoking the url: "/CreatePost" with form-data "name: 'A new post'",

end up trying to find and call an action named "A new post" and not "CreatePost".

Can I instruct the routing in asp.net to favor url-segments rather than form-data? or to just ignore anything other than the url overall? Preferably not only per parameter or action but over the entire controller.

This happened to be a problem here, which could of course be easily fixed with a renamed parameter, but I'm worried this could cause bugs elsewhere since I was not expecting this behavior  when writing my controllers and I frequently use form-data as if it is not affecting routing. So I much rather just turn it off completely and opt-in where needed instead. Is that possible?

And yes, I know the action-method should be "CreatePost" and not "HandlePostServiceAction", but the actions I invoke here are dynamic and not known at compile-time. So it looks a bit weird.

What I guess I want is a "FromRoute"-attribute to apply to the entire controller and not for every parameter.

Comment: Hi @Andreas Zita, A bit confused with your scenario, if you use `[HttpPost("{name}")]
`, and send request /CreatePost, the name parameter will receive CreatePost.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment! The thing is, if you also include form-data in that request with a parameter "name", it's value will be injected instead. It overrides the route by default. If I add [FromRoute] to the action-parameter it works as expected. Without it, the form-param takes precedence. Which is/was very unexpected for me at least.